# How to express in a first-order language that a graph is $k$-colorable?

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic, graph-theory, first-order-logic, model-theory

do you think it is possible to express via first-order formulas that an undirected graph is $k$-colorable?
I am thinking about a structure $A=\{V, E \}$ that if it satisfies that, than it is $k$-colorable.

Comment: What are your thoughts?  Where are you stuck?  What tools are available to you?  Please **edit the question** to include this information.  Questions that don't show evidence of an independent effort to reach a solution usually are not well received here.

Comment: The question seems perfectly clear to me.

Comment: Showing that something is not expressible by a first-order formula is not straightforward. Are you familiar with ultraproducts and Łoś's theorem?

Answer (score 3):

First note that, for each odd natural number $n$, there is a first-order sentence $A_n$ expressing "there is no cycle of length $n$," and also note that a graph is $2$-colorable if and only if it satisfies all these infinitely many sentences.

Now suppose, toward a contradiction, that there were a ingle sentence $B$ expressing $2$-colorability. Then $B$ would be a consequence of the infinite set of sentences $\{A_n:n\text{ odd}\}$. By the compactness theorem, $B$ would be a consequence of some finite subset $F$ of this infinite set. Let $n$ be an odd number such that $A_n\notin F$. Then an $n$-cycle satisfies all the sentences in $F$ and therefore satisfies $B$, but is not $2$-colorable, contrary to the choice of $B$.

So $2$-colorability is not expressible by a first-order sentence. The same is true for $k$-colorability with larger values of $k$, but I think the proof needs to be more complicated, because there's no analog of the "no odd cycles" characterization of $2$-colorability.

Comment: There exist some known examples of regular graphs with arbitrarily large girth and arbitrarily large chromatic number, see eg http://math.uchicago.edu/~may/REU2016/REUPapers/Tsui.pdf . Since it's easy to construct regular Schreier graphs with arbitrarily large girth and chromatic number 2, I suspect a much more delicate compactness argument will work for $\chi$-colorability in general for each fixed $\chi\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @EdwardH i don't think it needs to be all that delicate. for each natural n  "there are no cycles of length n" is first-order expressible, so if by contradiction we had some first order sentence saying "G is not k-colorable" we could apply the result you mention and compactness to get an acyclic graph with arbitrarily high chromatic number.

Comment: @AlexanderTenenbaum Yes, you are correct. Sorry for making things needlessly complicated and thank you for this observation.